# View 3D view of a Website or a Web Page

Tags: 3d

i wondered how we could make a 3D view of a 2D (a Web Page in this example).

You wouldnt understand what im trying to say:

Here's an example of what im tryin to achieve:-

```
https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline
```

you can watch the video and i want to know how you can make a camera move around the 2D place of a Web Page.

Answer (score 1):

The "3D" effects in this video are probably done with a professional video program and 3D manipulation of "photos" (web page pictures) and video. There are camtasia (screen recorder) zoom videos of live 3D desktop effects on youtube. Where different live 3d program effects are zoomed up on.

A loose search at youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6-NmtZ0zpE and related, shows some of the real time screen recorded videos.  Basically take a 3d desktop or shell, or one of the 3D browsers [Google 3d browser](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d%20browser&hl=en&prmd=imvnsa&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=cW5dT7ziEKvYiQLB3qWXDw&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQsAQ&biw=1209&bih=806) that exist, and record it using some good screen recorder software.

Comment: Something like Adobe After Effects should be able to produce a video just like the one on Facebook with little external help, as it has some rudimentary 3D (compared to full-blown 3D editors) capabilities and very extensive 2D effects.

Comment: oh ok ! so u say it isnt anything related to 3d screen capturing ?